# SQL SUM doubling even though there's only 1 row of data

Tags: sql, sum

I have a SUPER simple query.  No joins, nothing.  For some reason though, my sum doubles.  The query is simply:

```
SELECT SUM(ORDER_AMT) AS Total 
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE CUSTOMER = '123' 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.
```

I expect to see 1,000 (as ORDER_AMT for this customer is 1,000 and they only have one record in the ORDERS table) but I'm getting 2,000.  IF I do:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER = '123'
```

I only get a single row of data and the value for ORDER_AMT is 1,000 (the only reason I'm looking for a sum is that this is part of a stored procedure and other customer may have multiple order so I really do want a sum for them).

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: are Order and Orders two different tables ? or was that a mistype?

Comment: What is the data type of `ORDER_AMT`?

Comment: As @KarthikGanesan points out- if there is no spelling error you are most probably having two different copies of this table in your DB - or a DataView of that name.

Comment: Sorry Karthik.  That was indeed a typo.  There is only one table involved.  Also, the data is DECIMAL

Comment: maybe you should post your stored procedure

Comment: I haven't completed it yet.  I just started creating the SQL for it when I came across this

Comment: what happens if you execute the select outside the SP?

Comment: I am executing outside of the SP.  I haven't created the SP yet.  I'm simply in the process of writing the SQL that will become the SP.

Comment: If you don't mention OP nick, @McNets in this case, he wont receive any notification.

Comment: Could you post table schema?

Comment: @McNets I just realized, I'm not querying a table.  I'm querying a view.  (The database in question has over 1,600 tables and maybe 200 views, so it can get a little complex.)  I opened up the design of the view and it's hitting another 12 tables.  I think I may need to head back to the old drawing board

Comment: Please paste view code, and table schema, created from view recordset (select *  into [table] from [view]). Otherway question in uncomplete, and cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a group by if you're using the sum() function. The sum() function already takes an aggregate of everything in the returned table.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone for their help here.  Once I went to find the schema I realized what I was querying against wasn't in the tables.  I found it over in views.  Digging in to the design of the view I was able to directly pull the value I needed (out of an actual payment table that was in the view query) and bypass the view altogether.  Still not sure what happened but as I am now getting accurate data from elsewhere, I'm going to drop it.